# How can to java applet program in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

Now I am using the JDK 18 version. When I tried to execute the applet program I am getting an error telling could not find or load the main class sun.applet.appletviewer.

I saw many videos on YouTube to solve this problem, they are asking me to uninstall the current version of the JDK file and install JDK 8 which allows running an applet program in eclipse, is there any other way to solve this problem professionally?

Comment: Applets are a discontinued technology, originally intended to run in browsers, but there no longer supported. So you might reconsider swing or javafx.

Answer (score 0):

Java 17 removed supports for Applets, and most browsers had long since removed their support for them. The only way they can work is with a version of Java before Java 9. I don't want to be mean, but you solve this problem "professionally" by moving to a different technology.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/migratingfromapplets-2872444.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can install Eclipse *Applet Runner* plug-in and run your applet in it: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/applet-runner-eclipse

Note that you can also download it from the application website https://www.japplis.com/applet-runner/